# SSIS Scheduled Job is Failing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have scheduled job with some packages which runs once in a week. For past 4 weeks the job is failing and I used to run it manually whenever it failed.

This week its failing with error "Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage: 422217900097536' in database 'EDGDBC' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup".

Looks like disk space issue. What is the resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From Management Studio right click database EDGDBC and select properties

Select files, and in the autogrowth column if you don't see "unrestricted growth" click the ... button next to the file.

Check the "Enable Autogrowth" check button and repeat the process for all files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your disk space is actually getting low.
2. Verify that your primary filegroup has space available
3. You - could add another file on a different set of disks for the primary file group if needed.